# Macro interacting with swf in powerpoint 2007

Tags: vbscript, macros, flash, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm currently working on a powerpoint presentation which contains an embedded swf file. The swf file is a small app that does some calculations.

Embedding the swf file was no problem, but I would like to know whether or not it's possible to interact with the swf (e.g read values from the swf) with a VB macro from powerpoint 2007?

My main goal is to get values from the calculations (in the swf) and use these values in later slides of the presentation.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with SWFs other than popping them into PPT and letting them play, but if the SWF exposes any properties/methods, it would be through the shape's .OLEFormat.Object object, most likely.

Or if you have control of the SWF, you might be able to modify it to call subs or set variables exposed publically from PPT.